# How Task.Run avoids deadlocks in async code?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, deadlock

I've read from [async guidelines](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskrun-for-long-running-work-that-blocks-the-thread) that if we HAVE to block the async code on a UI thread(or single threaded `SyncContext`) then we must block it by using

```
Task.Run(()=>AsyncFunc()).Result
```

inorder to avoid potential deadlocks.

> quote from the link:
>
> ```
> public string DoOperationBlocking()
> {
>     // Bad - Blocking the thread that enters.
>     // DoAsyncOperation will be scheduled on the default task scheduler, **and remove the risk of deadlocking.**
>     // In the case of an exception, this method will throw an AggregateException wrapping the original exception.
>     return Task.Run(() => DoAsyncOperation()).Result;
> }
> ```

note this part:

> ...and remove the risk of deadlocking.

But I'm a bit confused on how this would prevent such thing. Based on my understanding, `Task.Run` passes the paramater as a `Task` to `ThreadPool` which does NOT have a SyncContext hence not blocking our current thread in the `SyncContext`. But let's see what actually happens **based on my understanding**:

1. The `Result` call waits on the task that has been returned from `Task.Run` and blocks the current thread
2. `AsyncFunc` has now done its job and it is ready to return. It actually can since it is not bound to return to any specific thread (this task does not have the SyncContext).
3. The task that wrapped this `AsyncFunc` (`AsyncFunc` is the task in step 2) is ready to return, but the wrapped `Task` is created in the UI thread hence it has the `SyncContext`.
4. The current `SyncContext` has only one thread and it is blocked due to the call to `Result`
5. the wrapped task cannot be marked as completed and set the result
6. deadlock

Comment: How and where do read this out of the linked text?

Comment: @Fildor you need to scroll down a little bit.

Comment: @Fildor two parapraphs under the link, starting from DEADLOCK, the first example in DoOperationBlocking class

Comment: All the places in the linked web page seem to indicate that doing that is Bad.

Comment: Ah now I see where you get that.

Comment: @juharr read the updated question where I explicitly mark where they mention this would avoid deadlocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 5. The wrapped task cannot be marked as completed and set the result

AFAIK your understanding here is incorrect. The wrapped task (`AsyncFunc`) can mark the wrapper one as completed from another thread (and nothing prevents the wrapped one from completion because it executes on the default scheduler on thread pool, see the [implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5450) and does not use the `SynchronizationContext`).

If you check [`Task.Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>?> function)` implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,3d9b659e18790bf4) you will see that it uses internally [`UnwrapPromise`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,4763c57feca6e20e) which internally adds [callback](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,6833) for the wrapped task if it is not already completed - `outerTask.AddCompletionAction(this);` (`outer` is the wrapped async task in this context), since the default scheduler was used the continuation does not use the `SynchronizationContext`, so there is no deadlock.

Also `Task.Result` [implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs,441) can shed some light. For not finished tasks it calls [`GetResultCore`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs,464) which does the blocking which combines [`SpinWait`ing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/spinwait) and [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=net-7.0) which can be signaled from another thread.

Comment: this callback will run within the current SyncContext(with one thread) which is blocked. Then how will it ever get a chance to run in this scenario?

Comment: @ClassY Why do you think that? Continuation is run by the same default scheduler and will be run on thread pool (I would assume even in the same thread in which the async task was completed). As far as I understand effect is similar as specifying `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Since if the child task uses ConfigureAwait(false) then it will NOT affect the callers SynContext. It will only affect the currenly running function and everything it calls within itself(note that the task above it (which could also be another async function) is not affected by the usage of ConfigureAwait in the called function). This affect applies from top to bottom not bottom to top.

Comment: @ClassY in the discussed example `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not used at all (and my explanation does not assume it is).

Comment: thanks for your time and I'm sorry if I phrased my comment badly. You said the effect is similar if I had specifed ConfigureAwait(false). If we assume that then my comment should contradict what you said.

Comment: @ClassY please read [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) article. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` through all async hierarchy can be used to prevent the deadlock in sync-over-async scenario (though again, it still is a bad practice).

Comment: @ClassY Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250756/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-classy).

Answer (score 1):

> The task that wrapped this `AsyncFunc` (`AsyncFunc` is the task in step 2) is ready to return, but the wrapped `Task` is created in the UI thread hence it has the `SyncContext`.

It is true that the `Task` is created on the UI thread, but it is not generated by an `async` method. The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method is not implemented with the [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) keyword. The `SynchronizationContext` plays a role in the `await` points (it is captured [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait)). There are no `await` points in a non-`async` method.

Take a look at this asynchronous method for example:

```
Task MyYield()
{
    TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => tcs.SetResult());
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Notice the absence of the `async` keyword. You can call `MyYield().Wait();` on the UI thread as much as you want. No deadlock will happen¹. The completion of the [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource) does not depend on the UI thread. You can imagine that the `Task.Run` is implemented in a similar way.

¹ <sub>Unless the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) has reached its maximum size, and all the available threads are permanently blocked.</sub>